# Is it possible to do do polymorphic row (or record) projections in PureScript?

Tags: purescript, rowtype

I'm  curious if there is a polymorphic function like `project` below, or if it is possible to design such a function in PureScript:

```
type MyRecRow = (a :: Int, b :: String)

type MyRec = Record MyRecRow

type MyRecA = {a :: Int}

foo :: MyRec
foo = {a: 5, b: "bbb"}

bar :: MyRecA
bar = project(foo)
```

My current understanding suggestions this might be possible at the type level using things like Prim.Row's `Cons` and `Lacks`, and possibly something like `purescript-heterogeneous` for the implementation, though that is a bit beyond my currently fluency level with PureScript.

Comment: The `pick` function in `purescript-record-extra` seems to do what you want. https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-record-extra/3.0.1/docs/Record.Extra#v:pick

Comment: `pick` is the correct answer, thank you